# sendKeys is opening a new tab in Chrome

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
inputField = driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="lst-ib"]'));
driver.sleep(1000);
var d = "hello test : , ! ";
inputField.sendKeys(d);
```

This is supposed to type  in input box `hello test : , !`, but when I use symbol like `:` or `!` it is opening chrome://settings/help tab in Chrome, but if I remove those symbols its working fine:

```
var d = "hello test"; // works fine
var d = "hello : test"; // opens new tab
var d = "hello ! test"; // opens new tab
```

Comment: Which Selenium Clients are you using Java/C#?

Comment: Nodejs , webdriver

Comment: I think you can fix it by using protractor 5.2.0 and update chromedriver to 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

As per your code I guess you are trying to **`sendKeys`** to the **`Search Box`** of **`Google Home Page`**. Here is your own code with a simple tweak which works well:

> **driver.sleep(1000);** is induced to show the user that **`sendKeys`** works just perfect and is not intended for Testing & Production instances.

```
inputField = driver.findElement(by.name("q"));
var d1 = "hello test";
var d2 = "hello : test";
var d3 = "hello ! test";
inputField.sendKeys(d1);
driver.sleep(1000);
inputField.sendKeys(d2);
driver.sleep(1000);
inputField.sendKeys(d3);
driver.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: It was working fine for me too , suddenly after chrome update , I am unable to...btw what is the tweak ? It doesnt work for me ,

Comment: The `xpath` you have constructed for the intended `WebElement` is flaky. We need to construct an accurate one.

Comment: even your code results me same , I guess its bug in my latest chrome , it types hello test , but when it types hello : it opens new tab

Comment: What are you `Selenium`, `Node` & `webdriver` version?

Comment: selenium-webdriver - 3.6.0  .. node v6.9.1 .. chrome .. Version 63.0.3239.40